# Nesting CSS selectors in material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, css-in-js, makestyles

I can't figure out how to do the simplest thing in CSS using *makeStyles* from material-ui.

Imagine this super simple example:

```
<div classNames={clsx(wrapper, post.new && classes.new)}>
  <p classNames={text}>Post</p>
  <p> Something else </p>
</div>
```

The styles are really easy as well:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  wrapper: {
    // styles
  },
  text: {
    // styles
  },
  new: { 
    text: { 
      color: 'red', // this does not work, why? :[
    } 
  }
});
```

You can probably guess by now what the problem here is. I want wrapper to have `new` class sometimes and when it happens `text` gets red. That's it. I have absolutely no clue how to do this.

I know there's `'& .something'` but this looks like a bad approach and I don't even know exact class name for text because classes are gibberish ( `makeStyles-text-somerandomnumber`). I don't want to add .new class to everything that needs extra styles, what if I there are multiple paragraphs that need different styles? Impossible to maintain. I guess I must be missing something, it's so trivial, yet, no idea how to do this!

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
className={`wrapper ${this.state.something}`}
```

I see that your post is tagged with `reactjs`, if you are using React you can just dynamically apply the classes by whatever their state is.

Don't forget the backticks for template literals.

Comment: This is a good advice, but won't work in my case, I don't want to add extra class to "text" element. What if I had 150 paragraphs that need to be red? I'd have to add the class to every single one of them.

Comment: So make a paragraph component that has it's own state and then render each paragraph with the content you want as props that is passed into the element? You could even make a prop that toggles the element state to be new or not.